Let the hexagon $ABCDEF$ such that $\frac{MA}{MB}=\frac{NB}{NC}= \frac{PC}{PD}= \frac{QD}{QE}= \frac{RE}{RF}= \frac{SF}{SA}=k>0$
The problem
Let the hexagon $ABCDEF$ and the points $M, N, P, Q, R, S$
be on the sides $AB, BC, CD, DE, EF,$ and $FA$, respectively, such that
$\frac{MA}{MB}=\frac{NB}{NC}= \frac{PC}{PD}= \frac{QD}{QE}= \frac{RE}{RF}= \frac{SF}{SA}=k>0$
Let us denote by $G_1, G_2, G_3, G_4, G_5$ and $G_6$ the distinct centroids of the triangles $ACD, BDE, CEF, DAF, EAB,$ and $FBC$, respectively. Prove that
the segments $(G_1G_2), (G_3G_4)$ and $(G_5G_6)$ are concurrent if and only if
the triangles $MPQ, PRS$ and $RMN$ have the same centroid.
The idea
I assume we have to take $2$ cases:
case $1$: if $k\in(0,1)$, for which we have this drawing:

case $2$: if $k>1$ for which we have this drawing:

However, for both of these cases, it would be helpful to use the formula that says $\vec{OM}=\frac{1}{1+k} \vec{OA}+\frac{k}{1+k} \vec{OB}$
I hopee one of you can help me! Thanks1

this looks perfectly bashable with your approach of vectors if you just continue expressing everything in terms of $A,B,C,D,E,F$. I am assuming that, since the RHS is dependent on the new points while LHS isn't, there will be a nice cancellation of things.
Also, there is another case where all these points are actually on the sides, not on the left or right of the sides.

@dezdichado I dont understand how i should continue my approach, can you wite a bit more well explained answer or even a hint

I will leave a hint here and you can fill in the details.
Fix an origin $O$ and a vector $\vec{OX}$ as just $\vec{X}.$  Then, $3\vec{G_1} = \vec{A}+\vec{C}+\vec{D}$ and $3\vec{G_2} = \vec{B}+\vec{D}+\vec{E}$ and any point $T$ on the line containing points $G_1$ and $G_2$ is given by:
$$3\vec{T} = x(\vec{A}+\vec{C}+\vec{D}) + (1-x)(\vec{B}+\vec{D}+\vec{E})= $$
$$=\vec{D} + x(\vec{A} + \vec{C}) + (1-x)(\vec{B} + \vec{E}), \quad x\in\mathbb{R}.$$ You can now do the same for the equations of lines passing through the other two segments.
On the other hand, the centroid, $G$, of $\triangle MPQ$ is:
$$3\vec{G} = \vec{M}+\vec{P}+\vec{Q} = \alpha (\vec{A}+\vec{C} + \vec{D}) + (1-\alpha)(\vec{B} + \vec{D} + \vec{E}) = $$
$$ =\vec{D+} \alpha(\vec{A}+\vec{C}) + (1-\alpha)(\vec{B} + \vec{E})$$
Now it should be obvious what to do - in fact, this immediately solves one direction of the if and only if (which one ?).

Can you please add more details idk what to do forward...thanks
